Review audit tasks betray themselves by a different look
I am quite regularly reviewing late answers.
Lately (I don't remember exactly for how long, maybe two months?) audit tasks betray themselves. The Q/A container is always behind an overlay of some kind.

Also there is some z-index issue when flagging such task.

This means the audit tasks are recognizable at first glance which totally defeats their purpose.
The only JS script source I am blocking is GTM. Hopefully review-queues don't depend on some GTM snippet!
I am using Firefox 124.0.2 with dark theme set in preferences, should it matter.
Is this a bug?

I searched for questions regarding this bug but at no avail. Thanks for the hint!
